# Async/await pair in visual basic not working as it should?

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, async-await

So, I have the following layout in a part of my program written in Visual Basic 2015: (the following is just pseudocode to make it easier to understand)

```
Async Button_Click_Event_Handler {
   ... (Synchronous code)
   Await DoWork()
}

Async Sub DoWork() {
   ... (Synchronous Code)
   Dim InitDB_t = Task.Run(Sub() InitDatabase())
   ... (Both synchronous and awaited code)
   Await InitDB_t
   ... (Both synchronous and awaited code)
}

Async InitDatabase() {
   ... (Synchronous Code)
   Await SQLConnection.OpenAsync()
   ... (Synchronous Code)
}
```

Now, what I wanted to accomplish is the following flow:

```
Button_Click_Event_Handler ---> DoWork() ---> Start executing InitDatabase(),
while other things that don't depend on the Database get executed --->
After the call "Await InitDB_t" be ***100% SURE*** that the database has been initialized,
i.e. InitDatabase() task has been completed, so that things that depend on it get executed.
```

Apparently, it seems that VB doesn't respect my flow, or I simply don't understand exactly how `Await` works, because every single time I run it, I get an exception below `Await InitDB_t` when I actually use the - assumed initialized - DB and upon checking, I realized to my surprise that `InitDatabase()` hasn't **actually** finished, but is still "awaiting" on `SQLConnection.OpenAsync()`, even though `Await InitDB_t` has returned!!!

How can I alter my code, without getting a deadlock, since using `Task.Wait()` would actually block the current execution thread (and thus, I would be **100% sure** that anything after it is executed after the DB has been fully initialized, but, oops, I would get a deadlock) and since I need contexts to update some GUI elements?

**Edit 1**: OK, after further debugging it seems that my logic is more wrong than I expected, since another exception arises: When I execute `InitDatabase()` I do some GUI assignments too, such as `label_p.Content = "finished"` which throws an exception because I am in a different thread than the GUI one. So, I would like corrections for both exceptions now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is that you wrapped `InitDatabase()` with new thread.
Task returned by `Task.Run` will completes before `OpenAsync` completes.

```
Dim InitDB_t = Task.Run(Sub() InitDatabase())
```

If `InitDatabase` is properly created asynchronous method (you didn't show full context) then it will return `Task`.

```
 Private Async Function InitDatabase() As Task
     ' ... (Synchronous Code)
     Await SQLConnection.OpenAsync()
     ' ... (Synchronous Code)
 End Function
```

And `Task` will be returned back to caller on `Await SQLConnection.OpenAsync()` line, when `OpenAsync` completes execution continue to the next line.

So inside `Task.Run` this method will return value before `OpenAsync` completes.
Because method `InitDatabase` completes execution the status of task `InitDB_t`
 will be `RanToCompletion` too while actually `OpenAsync` not finished yet.

Because all your method are asynchronous you don't need `Task.Run` at all and all operations can be executed on same thread - which will successfully updates UI controls.

First be sure that `InitDatabase` return `Task`. I suggest to rename method to `InitDatabaseAsync`, suffix "Async" is added by conventions, but I found it very usefull.

```
 Private Async Function InitDatabaseAsync() As Task
     ' ... (Synchronous Code)
     Await SQLConnection.OpenAsync()
     Me.MyLabel.Text = "Finished"
     ' ... (Synchronous Code)
 End Function
```

Then same approach with `DoWork` method - always return `Task` with `Async` method. Exception is UI eventhandlers - with them you can use `Async Sub`.
If you not returning a `Task` then your method will work like "Fire and Forget", but you will not notice any exception thrown inside those methods.

```
 Private Async Function DoWorkAsync() As Task
     ' ... (Synchronous Code)
     Dim InitDB_t = InitDatabaseAsync()
     ' ... (Both synchronous and awaited code)
     Await InitDB_t
     ' ... (Both synchronous and awaited code)
 End Function
```

Then in eventhandler

```
Private Async Sub Button_Click_Event_Handler()
    ' ... (Synchronous code)
    Await DoWorkAsync()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

> I realized to my surprise that InitDatabase() hasn't actually finished, but is still "awaiting" on SQLConnection.OpenAsync(), even though Await InitDB_t has returned!!!

This can happen if you use `Async Sub`. You should only use `Async Sub` for event handlers.

> When I execute InitDatabase() I do some GUI assignments too, such as label_p.Content = "finished" which throws an exception because I am in a different thread than the GUI one.

Remove the call to `Task.Run`. You don't need it anyway, since your code is asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

Try using like below

```
Await DoWork()..GetAwaiter().GetResult()
```

You can use this code inside any Non Async Function or Sub to call Async methods.

Refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/210742/how-do-you-call-an-async-function-from-main-on-a-c)